# What app for tracking sessions on iPhone?

Tags: online, pokertracker

I'm looking for a good application for tracking my poker sessions on iPhone. More specifically, I want to track the result of my sessions and get various stats like total profit, hour rate etc.

What good applications that can do this are out there?

Comment: What exactly do you want to track? I believe there are apps for the iPhone that will allow you to track your session, but I dont think they record hand histories etc.

Comment: Hey Laurent, could you please clarify your question ? **What exactly do you want to track?**

Comment: I want to track the result of my sessions and get various stats like total profit, hour rate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Poker Analytics since a year and I love it. I tried a few other apps a while ago but none were convincing...Poker Analytics is the most simple and powerful I tried. I also really like the style.

http://www.poker-analytics.net/

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Full disclaimer - I'm the developer of this app.

I developed Live Poker Manager for this purpose. It's very simple to use; you can enter your sessions into the app, and then view stats/graphs for your them. You can also record players in the app, as well as keep notes on them.

There's also a lite version, so you can try it out first.

Here's the website:

http://live-poker-manager.webflow.com

Answer (score 0):

I love Poker Income. Its a handy little app, very easy to use and I like how it tracks sessions. Its very affordable and has never let me down.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded trial version of a few, but haven't really tried them out fully. I settled for RunGood which has a nice user interface and have worked well with a few important stats.

But I'm also looking for an upgrade to a better app with more app presented in a way that you don't have to have a Ph.D in stats to understand.